# trying to import a external component but returns error

Tags: vue.js

Iam trying to import this component into my vue page

https://github.com/damienroche/vue-mj-daterangepicker

at the top of my script element of my vue page i have this

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import DateRangePicker from 'vue-mj-daterangepicker'
import 'vue-mj-daterangepicker/dist/vue-mj-daterangepicker.css'
Vue.use(DateRangePicker)
```

And also in my export default i have this

```
components: {
    DateRangePicker
}
```

My html

```
<date-range-picker from="2018-04-23T10:26:00.996Z" to="2019-04-23T10:26:00.996Z" panel="range" @update="update"/>
```

I get this error when loading my page on the web

```
[Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.

found in

---> <DateRangePicker>
   <BookingStatistics> at resources/assets/js/views/BookingStatistics.vue
     <Root>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DateRangePicker` is a plugin that registers the component globally without registering in components option:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import DateRangePicker from 'vue-mj-daterangepicker'
import 'vue-mj-daterangepicker/dist/vue-mj-daterangepicker.css'
Vue.use(DateRangePicker)
```

and use it directly `<date-range-picker ... />` **without** :

<del>`components: { DateRangePicker }`</del>